# upload picture on timeline album of user using facebook c# sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I want to upload picture to timeline of user or page.
I am able to upload picture to users wall but it has created new album with my application name. But i want to upload picture to timeline album of user.

I have uploaded picture using bellow code

```
 var result = client.Post("/"+ id +"/photos", postparameters);
```

Comment: Then you’ll have to get the album id first, and post the photo to that album. Will require additional permission.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.I just filtered id of the album where I wanted to post picture & passed it in place if "id" of above code.

```
 var result = client.Post("/"+ album_id +"/photos", postparameters);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get album id dynamic :

> dynamic albums = app.Get("me/albums");
>
> string AlbumId="";
>
> foreach (dynamic albumInfo in albums.data)
>
> {
>
> ```
>   if(albumInfo.name == "Timeline Photos"){AlbumId=albumInfo.id; break;}
> ```
>
> }

and the you can use AlbumId to post in the album .

Answer (score 0):

**msm2020** solution do the trick but don't forget to add the albums permission: [user_photos](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/album/)